# How can I prevent map moving and zooming on click in LeafletJS?

Tags: javascript, css, api, leaflet, geo

I have a Leaflet JS map with click events on icons, that show a popup with more information. On a live site, the map behaves oddly: clicking on the marker involuntarily moves the maps and popups to the top left corner, it zooms, and the popup is not visible.

In the codepen below, although not near complete, the map behaves as expected (here you can also inspect the code):

https://codepen.io/francofx2/pen/XWYmgyd

The issue happens when I migrate it to my live site:
https://junglapeumayen.cl/el-parque-test-mapa/

I've been messing with CSS to no avail, here you can see the part that controls the popbox boxes:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.map_marker_popup_img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

I could also be a JS problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any zooming or misplacement of the popup. The map does pan a little, but that is in order to accommodate the popup that opens.

Comment: You can set `autoPan=false` on the popup options.

Comment: @MarkSetchell
@Terry 

thanks a lot! the ```autoPan: false``` property did it